# Plotting Multiple Models MSE over Many Samples in R

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I would like to create `boxplots` for total `MSE` for each of my models to show variability in the models' errors. What is the best way to sample and fit models many times over in order to generate a `boxplot` showing the distribution of the errors.

For each model, I will generate predictions for all data (Train and Test). I will then calculate the Train `MSE` and the Test `MSE` by `subsetting` the predictions accordingly. The following function will calculate both `MSE` values simultaneously.

Is there a better way to re-sample and `plot` the MSE for each model by each re-sample? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 calcMSE = function(model,modelLabel,dataSet,trainIdx,newX=NULL)
 {
   # The predict method for glmnet will need to be called differently from the
   # other predict methods.
   if ("glmnet" %in% class(model)) {
     predVals = predict(model,newX,type="response")
   } else {
     predVals = predict(model,data)
   }
   MSE = list(
     name = modelLabel,
     train = mean((predVals[trainIdx] - data$y[trainIdx])^2),
     test = mean((predVals[-trainIdx] - data$y[-trainIdx])^2)
   )

   return(MSE)
 }

 modelMSEs = data.frame(Model = rep(NA,8),Train.MSE = rep(NA,8),Test.MSE =      rep(NA,8))

 modelMSEs[1,] = calcMSE(modelA1,"A1",Data,trainIdx)
 modelMSEs[2,] = calcMSE(modelA2,"A2",Data,trainIdx)
 modelMSEs[3,] = calcMSE(modelB1,"B1",Data,trainIdx)
 modelMSEs[4,] = calcMSE(modelB2,"B2",Data,trainIdx)
 modelMSEs[5,] = calcMSE(modelC1,"C1",Data,trainIdx)
 modelMSEs[6,] = calcMSE(modelC2,"C2",Data,trainIdx)

 print(modelMSEs)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Package ‘cvTools’ allows one to plot box and whisker plots of results from a k-folds CV w/ function bwplot.cv. This might be a better route. Thanks.